# Messages processing policy for Service Bus connector in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, cloud, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I have Azure Logicapp that processes messages from Service Bus topic using **When one or more messages arrive in a topic (peek-lock)** connector. 
[image]

I've sent 40 messages into Service bus with the same *session-id*
[image]

As we know from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#when-one-or-more-messages-arrive-in-a-topic-(peek-lock))  this connector can process 20 messages per run. **BUT** what we see here.

*First run*
I have another time zone (UTC+3), so hours have a shift
[image]

*Second run*
[image: Second run]

*Third run*
[image: Third run]

Instead of two runs `20/20` we have three `1/20/19`

Why is this happen? I can't find an explanation in docs?

Comment: Hi keipa, could you please show a screenshot of the trigger of your logic app ?

Comment: @HuryShen done, the ticket is updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic app Service Bus does not guaranty batch processing to achieve this use [batch receiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-batch-process-send-receive-messages#create-batch-receiver)

It looks like the logic app will be triggered with the first message and the try to prefetch the next 20(default size) items and do that in for the next items.

> Some triggers, such as the When one or more messages arrive in a queue (auto-complete) trigger, can return one or more messages. When these triggers fire, they return between one and the number of messages that's specified by the trigger's Maximum message count property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus

Answer (score 1):

I would like to let you know that 20 is the default count in the connector, you can increase the count (Maximum Message Count). it may not completely resolve the issue you are facing but at least it will let you reduce the number of executions.

[image]

For fixing the first message issue, consider using batch receiver.

Answer (score 0):

The logic app does not wait for 20 messages to build up, since it cannot know if more will come. So it immediately fires for the first message. At this point, no other message is available to be processed.

Based on the timestamps in your screenshots, this is what happens:

1. You set up the logic app, configure the trigger etc.
2. You **start** sending messages
3. The logic app picks up the first message you sent
4. You finish sending your 40 messages
5. The logic app finishes processing the first message
6. The logic app picks up the next 20 messages
7. The logic app picks up the last 19 messages.

Comment: If you mention I finished sending messages **before** first run occurs. See timings. It's not an actual scenario

Comment: I am saying that you are still sending messages when the first run starts. This is what can be seen in the timings. 11:46:xx 11:47:xx => They are extremely close. Considering clock skew between your machine and the logic app, I bet that the logic app picked up only the first message because the others were not there yet.

Comment: No, I've tested that several times. And each time I have started trigger manually after the last message was sent. I've added screenshot with seconds. There are 20seconds delay between the last message sent and trigger start